# How can I modify my R code to produce a contour plot like this?

Tags: r, statistics

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
# first contour
m <- c(0,0)
n<-c(2*sqrt(2),2*sqrt(2))
sigma <- matrix(c(2,0,.0,2), nrow=2)
data.grid <- expand.grid(s.1 = seq(-6, 10, length.out=100), s.2 = seq(-6, 10, length.out=100))
q.samp <- cbind(data.grid, prob = mvtnorm::dmvnorm(data.grid, mean = m, sigma = sigma))
ggplot(q.samp, aes(x = s.1, y = s.2, z = prob)) +
  stat_contour(color = 'red') + 
  stat_contour(data = q.samp, aes(x = s.1, y = s.2, z = prob), color = 'green')

#sigma1 <- matrix(c(1,-.5,-.5,1), nrow=2)
set.seed(10)
data.grid1 <- expand.grid(s.1 = seq(-6, 40, length.out=200), s.2 = seq(-6, 40, length.out=200))
q.samp1 <- cbind(data.grid1, prob = mvtnorm::dmvnorm(data.grid1, mean = n, sigma = matrix(c(2, 1.2, 1.2, 2), nrow = 2)))
ggplot(q.samp1, aes(x = s.1, y = s.2, z = prob)) +
  stat_contour(color = 'red',bins = 12 ) + 
  stat_contour(data = q.samp, aes(x = s.1, y = s.2, z = prob), color = 'green',bins = 12)+geom_point(aes(x = 0, y =0))+
  geom_point(aes(x=2*sqrt(2),y=2*sqrt(2)))+xlab("Random slop")+ylab("Random intercept")
```

[image]

I want to plot the contour plot i get the plot above but I want to plot like following image

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific about which aspects of the difference matter to you (gray background, grid lines, multiple contours, numerical labels of centers, line connecting centers, etc. etc. etc.?)

Comment: line of between Two points,(0,0) and (2*\sqrt(2),2*\sqrt(2)). if you can create plot like second image its will be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is perfect, but it should get you started.  Basically you need `ggforce::geom_ellipse` and `ggplot2::geom_segment`.

```r
library(ggforce); library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
       geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, a = 3, b = 3, angle = 0), colour = "green") +
       geom_ellipse(aes(x0 = 2*sqrt(2), y0 = 2*sqrt(2), a = 4, b = 3, angle = pi/4), 
             colour = "purple") +
       coord_fixed() +
       theme_classic() +
       annotate(geom = "segment", x = 0, y = 0, xend = 2*sqrt(2), yend = 2*sqrt(2))
```

[image]